# How to subtract 2 dates on momentjs

Tags: momentjs

Hi im currently using momentjs for my dates in my project and im having a bit of trouble when subtracting 2 dates.

Here are my sample dates:

```
2016-10-08 10:29:23
2016-10-08 11:06:55
```

ive tried using the diff and subtract from the guide docs of momentjs but i got nothing.

And what if the date subtracted dates are more than 24 hours?

Thnks in advance.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You are correct, you can use moment's `diff` function to subtract two dates ([see my example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OYKfMnRjKsfhXd22m5uO)):

```
var date1 = moment('2016-10-08 10:29:23');
var date2 = moment('2016-10-08 11:06:55');
var diff = date2.diff(date1);
```

Diff will be equal to `2252000`, the number of milliseconds between the two date. [See documentation for more details](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

You can pass a second argument to `diff` with the measurement to use (years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds), so if you want to know the number of minutes between the two dates you can write:

```
var diffInMinutes = date2.diff(date1, 'minutes');
```

And you get `37` minutes.

Comment: What if the added dates are more than a day. ex 29:54:20 , 29 hours 54 minutes and 20 seconds? my result is always 23:59:59

Comment: for example? : var diff = date2.duration(date1); ? am i right?

Comment: Uhm, I think `duration` does not support `diff` operations. Just to understand, "29:54:20" is a date you receive in input? Without a day/month/year part?

Comment: No it gave me 1970-01-01 23:59:59 how can i know if the date is from 1970

Comment: I do not understand... Let's make an example, if the 2 dates are `var date1 = moment('2016-10-08 10:29:23');` and `var dateMoreThanADay = moment('2016-10-09 11:06:55');` and the diff is `var diff3 = dateMoreThanADay.diff(date1, 'minutes');`. The `diff3` has value `1477` which is the number of minutes between the 2 dates. The value is correct.